# Regex password validation, start letter doesn't count

Tags: regex, validation, passwords

I am creating regex for password validation. Password must start with letter, and must contain 1 uppercase and 3 lowercase letters among the other things.

This is what I got

```
^[a-zA-Z](?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*~].*[!@#$%^&~*])(?!.*(.)\1\1)[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{8,12}$
```

If I start with uppercase letter and there is not any other uppercase, validation is negative. It is same for lowercase.

- `Aasd23#$s`    invalid
- `Aasd23#$sA`   valid
- `aAas23$%6$`   invalid
- `aAas23$%6$a`  valid

Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you sure that at this point it's not easier to validate it by other means, if possible?

Comment: I've already spent too much time on this, so I have to finish

Comment: Simply place the [a-zA-Z] behind the lookaheads.

Comment: Isn't it there already? @SebastianProske

Comment: @revo no, it's directly after the `^`, thus evaluated before the lookaheads and not regocnigez inside those.

Comment: Yes and you said *behind the lookaheads* @SebastianProske

Comment: Yes, it should be placed behind the lookaheads to work correctly, like `^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*~].*[!@#$%^&~*])(?!.*(.)\1\1)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{8,12}$`

Comment: You just put it in front of them! @SebastianProske

Comment: @revo I honestly don't know what you are talking about. You know what a lookahead is? Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Ha ha. I think one of us is confused with meaning of two words: 1- *behind* 2- *in front of*. Does your dictionary define *behind* as *in front of*? @SebastianProske

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120885/discussion-between-sebastian-proske-and-revo).

Answer (score 0):

according to what you posted

```
^([a-zA-Z](?=(?:.*?[a-z]){3})(?=.*?[A-Z]).*)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/390)

Comment: I think the `[a-zA-Z]` should put into the lookaheads， so the regex should be like this `^(?=[a-zA-Z])(?=(?:.*?[a-z]){3})(?=.*?[A-Z]).*$`

Comment: @jcxu, per OP, 'If I start with uppercase letter and there is not any other uppercase, validation is negative. It is same for lowercase.', run your regex on his test passwords!